# Is a Middle Name a Given Name?

Tags: canada, paperwork, terminology, eta

My full name is four names long - First name, Middle name, Middle name, Last name.  Whenever asked for my *Given Name* I have always supplied my First name (not either of my middle names).

This week I have applied for a Canadian eTA, and put (as per usual) my First name only into the *Given Name(s)* field.

But now I'm wondering, should I have included my middle names also into that form?  In my passport I have all four names printed.

Comment: I know quite a few people with 4 part names where the first two were clearly 'first name' (it's what they always went by), the third was 'middle name' (and in one case, maiden name), and the fourth was 'last name'.  But I also know people with 4 part names where it's 'first/first/last/last' and 'first/middle/middle/last'.   Of course, the 'what you go by' doesn't always match 'legal'.  (my family goes by 'first/middle' when talking about each other, as there are so many with the same first & last names, and there are a *lot* of people at my work who go by their middle name)

Comment: Well, I have a 5-part name which goes first-first, middle, middle, last.  Causes no end of bureaucratic confusion.  You shouldn't enter parts that don't belong in a field into another though, adding middle names to first one would just cause confusion

Comment: Re: "In my passport I have all four names printed": Could you elaborate on this? Does your passport have a single 'Full Name' field with your entire full name? Or is your name divided among different fields in the passport? If the latter, then -- what are the fields, and which parts of your name are in each?

Comment: @GeorgeM but passports only have two name fields, called in the ICAO standard "primary identifier" and "secondary identifier."  The former is the family name, and the latter is the given names.  All of them.

Comment: All passports, or your passport?

Comment: I’ve always considered middle names to be more a part of the last name. Like in my case the ‘van den’ part. I also have 2 first names and that’s what I put in the given name part.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek "van den" are not middle names though. They are called "tussenvoegsel" in Dutch, which is part of the last name.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to the help file from the Canadian government for filling out the ETA it says the following on the application:

> **Given name(s) / first name(s)**
>   Please enter exactly as shown on your passport or identity document

Source: https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/eta/english.pdf (Page 11)

So you should put it in, exactly like it says on the passport.

If you're not sure what you should put in (not just two name forms, non-latin script) and your passport has a machine readable zone, you should probably use the names in the same grouping as done there.

[The format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport) are two lines at the bottom of the identity page of your passport where the first line is of the following format:
`P[4 unimportant letters][family name with blanks and other non-latin characters replaced by <]<<[given names also separated by <]` (`[]` being used by me to separate the fields).

Note that the ETA help pdf has some more detailed explanations that are worth reading for everyone with unusual name(s).

Comment: While the other answers explore the question of what a given name may or may not be, this is the practical answer: your visa needs to match your passport, so use whatever is printed in there.

Comment: This doesn't remove the confusion. For example, I have a first name, a patronymic, and a family name. My passport has bilingually named fields, and it calls them "name", "father's name" and "surname" in English. Nowhere does it use the term "given name" or "first name". Taking it rather literally, I would have expected only the "name" to be required by officials, since the patronymic doesn't function at all as a given name in Western cultures - but officials in Western Europe have seen it differently so far and tend to insist on the patronymic to be listed on forms asking for given name.

Comment: @rumtscho Interesting! Does it have a machine readable field at the bottom? If so I'd expect that to be the "correct" version, since its format only allows for given/family name. The PDF actually has additional information about what to do with "father's name" (leave it off), but I didn't think it would be helpful to the OP but it might be useful for others, I'll add them later.

Comment: @rumtscho, yes, when I gave the Chinese example I thought of Russian and realized that would only confuse things even more.  The patronymic isn't a first name, a given name, or a family name, but it *is* inherited.  E.g. Pyotr Ilyich Tchaikovsky's patronymic name is Ilyich, because Ilya was his father's given name. +1 for your comment and Voo's answer.

Comment: @Ray Do you know how the russian passport matches these names onto the machine readable fields? (Or does it not follow the standard? I'd think they would)

Comment: @Voo the Russian passport doesn't include the father's name in the machine readable zone.

Comment: @Voo the name in the machine readable zone is not separated by given/family name but by secondary/primary identifier.

Comment: @phoog How is that different? For the ones I know (obviously a very limited number) this maps well to the given/family name distinction while considering things like whether a title is part of the name or not.

Comment: @Voo it's probably not different; I'm just pointing out the terminology used in the specification.  It's just more neutral.  After all, a person's names don't necessarily come from the family, and they may not be given (for example if a person has changed his or her name to one of his or her own choosing).

Comment: @phoog Fair point. I still think that the MRZ is the best information for name grouping, but I don't have any authoritative source for it.

Comment: @RayButterworth: a literal patronymic is, by definition, *not* inherited. If the composer were called Pyotr Ilya Tchaikovsky, then you could maybe argue that the Ilya part (as well as the Tchaikovsky part) was inherited, but changing it to Ilyich makes it into a simple, literal, descriptive name term that tells you who his father was... i.e. a patronymic.

Answer (score 29):

"**my First name only into the Given Name(s) field**"

If it asked for "first name" a single name might be acceptable.  But it didn't.

Notice the "(s)".  That means that there can be more than one name.

Notice the "Given", that means all but your family name, which was inherited not given.

The form didn't ask for "First name"; it asked for "Given name(s)".

Many countries are improving their forms by saying "Given" rather than "First", since there are many societies where the first name is actually the family name.
(e.g. in Chinese, "Xi Jinping", "Xi Jin Ping", and "Xi Jin-Ping" are all valid Romanizations of "习近平".  "Xi" is first, but it is the family name.)

EDIT:  @Voo says that the form contains this instruction:

> Please enter exactly as shown on your passport or travel document.

That should remove any confusion.  Whatever names are on the passport you are going to be using should be the names you use on the form.  No more, no less.

Comment: *that means all but your family name* - where is that defined though? I've never known it to be used/required that way. And the  (s) to me would refer to names like Juan Pablo or Mary Kate where the first name is actually two names?

Comment: @Midavalo [It says so on the actual form](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/eta/english.pdf): "Given name(s) / first name(s): Please enter exactly as shown on your passport or identity document".

Comment: The reason it says "given name(s) / first name(s)" is because some people have multiple or hyphenated first names ("**Jean-Claude** Van Damme" / "**Jamie Lee** Curtis") - this comes down to how the parents have the birth certificate filled out, which contains separate fields for "first name(s)" / "middle name(s)" / "last name(s)".  It's the "first name(s)" that should be entered, not also the "middle name(s)" - check your birth certificate to make sure!

Comment: @Midavalo Indeed, the very form linked to here adds to the confusion by stating: "First name is also known as given name" (on page 11). When you put it all together you can work out what they want, but it is quite a poorly worded form. The phrase "Please enter exactly as shown on your passport", **by itself**, doesn't clarify anything at all as to whether one or multiple names are wanted. I therefore don't agree that "that should remove any confusion". The word "name(s)" is the only part which really helps to remove confusion.

Comment: @Chronocidal that is incorrect.  "Given names" comprises all the names other than the surname.  Look for a Canadian passport image online.  You'll see that it corresponds to the French "Prénoms," which is in the plural.   Middle names are just as given as are first names, and few cultures even make a distinction between them.

Comment: @phoog I feel like "all the names other than the surname" might be a bit too broad. East Slavic countries use a thing called *patronymic*, which is neither a given name nor a surname. Although at least in Russia and Ukraine it's not present in the international section of documents (i.e. not transcribed into English), I somehow have it on some English-language papers (even on one visa).

Comment: @Norrius I know about patronymics.  So yes, it seems that my saying "all names other than..." was overbroad or, perhaps more accurately, culturally biased.  Under the spec, it's up to each East Slavic country to decide whether to include the patronymic in either the primary or secondary identifier.  The acid test is whether it's present in the machine readable zone, especially if the question is whether to include it in an eTA application.  (I note that Iceland also uses patronymics, where they are generally used as the primary identifier and labeled as "surname" in the passport.)

Comment: @Chronocidal, I'd venture to say that English-speaking countries are the *only* ones where "middle name" exists as a category. Lots of countries have/use multiple given names, yes, but they don't categorize them differently, and their birth certificates (which also are not as universal a concept as English speakers seem to think) certainly don't have a "middle name" field.

Answer (score 4):

My name is (based on catholic), using the same form as David's answer:

- A: given (first) name
- B: middle name 1 (or second first name)
- C: middle name 2 (or third first name)
- D: middle name 3 (or fourth first name)
- E: family/surname

To make things even more complicated, my nickname is different than A; it is not in any official paper. So, on my passport I have to use A until D, and not my nickname.

Answer (score 4):

If your first and two middle names are printed under ‘Given names’ in your passport, and you are asked to provide ‘Given name(s)’ not ‘First name’, you should include all three.

Example: I just applied for an ESTA. I have a first and middle name (I’m known by my middle, not first, name), and my passport shows both names under ‘Given names’ and in the machine readable data section. When I uploaded this section during the application process, the system captured both names in the ‘Given names’ section of the application.

Other examples: https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/is-middle-name-part-of-given-name.202730/

Comment: Correct answer, but note that the [form](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/eta/english.pdf) itself rather unhelpfully does not make a distinction between first / given names ("First name is also known as given name" on page 11).

Answer (score 2):

At least for the Canadian passport application, Given name(s) IS defined as first AND middle names. There is no 'culture' argument involved here. However, there are actually some exceptions that would allow for your passport name to not match your DEC (ex. proof of citizenship, birth certificate) as long as it matches another form of ID (ex. driver's license). It is considered acceptable to drop one or more of your given names from appearing  on your passport; If your birth certificate lists your name as Jane Lyn Doe, you may apply for a passport requesting the name Jane Doe OR Lyn Doe, as long as one given name is present.  It also doesn't matter what order your given names come in; If your birth certificate lists your name as Jane Lyn Doe, your passport can have your name as Lyn Jane Doe. You just have to have another form of ID that matches this.

As far as applying for Visas, your name *should* appear as it does on your passport, so whichever decision you made for your passport, I advise doing the same for your visa. I personally ran into an issue adding my middle name to my visa application when my passport did not have it. Generally you won't run into an issue doing it the other way around though, dropping given names are more acceptable than adding them.

Comment: Welcome to [travel.se] and hope you stick around. While we definitely prefer answers with sources to back them up, this is a very common-sense one.

Answer (score 1):

Your title question is answered by your question itself: you consider your middle names as middle names, and not as your first name. Thus, I would complete applications so as to track your passport names as closely as possible.

In my culture, it'd go like this:

- A = given (first) name
- B = middle name #1
- C = middle name #2
- D = family/surname

Like this:

If the application has only two fields, enter A and D in the appropriate fields.

If the application has three fields, enter A in the first field, B and C (with an intervening space if possible) in the second field, and D in the third space.

Different cultures may attribute names differently.

Comment: But given names are all of the names other than the family name(s).

Comment: Depends on the culture, I think. In the culture I'm familiar with, it isn't. But may well be so in others. I'll amend the answer to reflect this.

Comment: If the application has one ‘Given names’ field, enter A, B, and C.

Comment: @David So what does it say in your passport? If A-C are listed under given name/first name that's what you have to put. And I can't imagine they aren't there.

Comment: @Voo My passport isn't at issue, wasn't my question. I have no middle name, and my passport shows my given name and my surname, in a completely expected fashion.

Comment: @David My point is that I have never seen a passport with more than two fields for name - given and family or however you want to phrase it. Hence A-C are lumped together in a single field, which is also what you're expected to use on any visa application or similar I've ever seen - that's certainly what's expected for the ETA. Just imagine the complications.

Comment: I agree, passports don't always display separate middle name "fields" on the bio page. (I don't know enough to assert that no passport does so.) Our US passports have only two fields: "given names" and "surname." The name fields do show up on passport _applications_, which is where the issue about where-to-put-it appears. My wife has a middle name, and her middle name is shown on the "given name" pane after her first given name.

Comment: @David which rather contradicts this answer, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe, but not necessarily. I don't know what the passport renewal form called for when she renewed in 2012, nor do I know how she filled-in the form.

Comment: @David what country is this? I just checked the passports of the US, Canada, the UK, Australia, New Zealand, and South Africa.  They all had one field for "given names," and one for "surname," except for Australia, which puts the entire name on two lines below the heading "name."  There's nowhere on any of those passports to include a middle name other than as part of the "given names," which is indeed how it appears on my US passport. The application form asks separately for first and middle names, and then puts them all in the "given names" field.

Comment: It's quite clear if you have a look at [ICAO 9303](https://www.icao.int/publications/pages/publication.aspx?docnum=9303), which works from a two-part division of the name.  It calls these two parts the primary and secondary identifier.  The relationship between these two fields and anyone's actual name is for each country to decide in line with its own naming culture, but basically in the European context the secondary identifier corresponds to the family name and the primary identifier to all the other names, which is why the US lists middle and first names together as "given names."

Comment: Thanks for the reference to ICAO 9303. It makes sense to me: if the application form has only two fields ("given" and "family," say) then all the names except the family name go in the first field, and the family name goes in the second field. Works for most of us, but the prevalence of these issues demonstrates that it doesn't work (at least not easily or clearly) for all. How does one does one deal with the Hispanic style of patronymic/matronymic without either referring to the holder by the matronymic, or discarding the patronymic?

Comment: As to Hispanic names, the answer is "with a good deal of confusion."  Spain labels the field "Apelidos/Surname/Nom," with only the Spanish label in the plural.  I don't know what other countries do when faced with a visa application from a Spanish passport holder, but I expect they mostly use them both. There was a question here or on [Expatriates.SE] (can't find it now) from someone who was naturalized in a Latin American country that required him to include his mother's family name in his passport, and the UK passport office wouldn't issue a new passport because it didn't match his old one.

Comment: @David In the Canadian case the answer seems to be "discard patronymic". Localizing names is fun business, but I hope the machine readable form on most passports gives some canonical answer (the Russian mrz excludes the patronymic as an example, no idea about Spanish passports).

Comment: @phoog Confusing indeed it is to fit
[Iberophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iberophone) [naming
conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iberian_naming_customs)
(like [Hispanophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_naming_customs),
[Lusophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_name#Number_of_names) ones)
within the naïve straits provided by Anglophone paper-pushers,
yet these are but a fraction of the
[multifarious falsehoods about people's
names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)
perpetrated upon the hapless world.